# angular.config with ngBootbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to change the locale of `ngBootbox` permanently, so I add an extra angular.config,

```
var app = angular.module('some_module',
   ['highcharts-ng', 'ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad',
   'ui.select', 'daterangepicker', 'ngBootbox']);

app.config(['ngBootbox', function(ngBootbox) {
  ngBootbox.setLocale ('zh_cn');
}]);
```

If I add this `setLocale` line to each controller it works great.

But not in the config part, I received an `$injector:unpr` error, not knowing why

Any ideas? Perhaps this is related to the ui-router? I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was unsupported

https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox/issues/29#issuecomment-160913828

The author added such ability in the latest commit.

Answer (score 0):

ngBootbox's provider is actually `$ngBootbox`, so your config should be something like this:

```
app.config(['$ngBootbox', function($ngBootbox) {
  $ngBootbox.setLocale ('zh_cn');
}]);
```